# relaxation equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

hi We consider the relaxation equation
$$
\partial_t f=\mathcal{L} f:=-v \cdot \nabla f+\rho_f M-f \quad \text { in } \quad(0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}^{2 d},
$$
on the unknown $f=f(t, x, v), t \geq 0, x, v \in \mathbb{R}^d$, with
$$
\rho_f(t, x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(t, x, v) d v, \quad M(v):=\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{d / 2}} \exp \left(-|v|^2 / 2\right) .
$$

We complement the equation with an initial condition
$$
f(0, x, v)=f_0(x, v) \quad \text { in } \quad \mathbb{R}^{2 d} .
$$

Question 1. A priori estimates and associated semigroup. We denote by $f$ a nice solution to the relaxation equation (3.1)-(3.2).
(a) Prove that $f$ is mass conserving.

(b) Prove that

$$
\left|\rho_g\right| \leq\|g\|_{L_v^2\left(M^{-1 / 2}\right)}, \quad \forall g=g(v) \in L_v^2\left(M^{-1 / 2}\right)
$$

and deduce that

$$\|f(t, \cdot)\|_{L_{x v}^2\left(M^{-1 / 2}\right)} \leq\left\|f_0\right\|_{L_{x v}^2\left(M^{-1 / 2}\right)} .
$$

the first question ,i already done and for question b i show the first inequality but i dont knoiw how to conclude imean how to show $$
\|f(t, \cdot)\|_{L_{x v}^2\left(M^{-1 / 2}\right)} \leq\left\|f_0\right\|_{L_{x v}^2\left(M^{-1 / 2}\right)} .
$$ , may be its stupid question but i apprecite your help

Comment: Which variables in $\nabla$ with respect to? Both $x$ and $v$ or just $x$?

Comment: hi, the variable in $\nabla$ is just x

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ \phi(t):= \| f\|_{L^2_{xv}(M^{-1/2})}^2=\int_{\mathbb R^{2d}} f^2 M^{-1/2} \,dv\,dx. $$ Differentiating $\phi$ with respect to $t$ and assuming that $f$ is nice enough to bring the derivative inside of the integral, we obtain that \begin{align*}
\phi’(t) &= 2\int_{\mathbb R^{2d}} f \partial_t f M^{-1/2} \, dv\,dx\\
&= -2\int_{\mathbb R^{2d}} f v\cdot \nabla f M^{-1/2} \, dv\,dx +2\int_{\mathbb R^{2d}} \rho_f f M^{1/2} \, dv \,dx -2\int_{\mathbb R^{2d}}f^2 M^{-1/2} \, dv \,dx\\
&= -2\int_{\mathbb R^{2d}} f v\cdot \nabla f M^{-1/2} \, dv\,dx +2\int_{\mathbb R^{2d}} \rho_f f M^{1/2} \, dv \,dx -2\phi(t).
\end{align*}

I’m assuming that $\nabla$ is only respect to the $x$ variables (it has to either be with respect to only $x$ or only $v$ since you are taking the dot product with $v\in \mathbb R^d$ and $x$ seems more likely to me). Then, $$ 2f v \cdot \nabla f = \operatorname{div}_x(f^2v),$$ so \begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R^{2d}} f v\cdot \nabla f M^{-1/2} \, dv\,dx &=\int_{\mathbb R^d} M^{-1/2} \bigg ( \int_{\mathbb R^d}\operatorname{div}_x(f^2v)\, dx \bigg ) \, dv =0
\end{align*} via integration by parts (assuming $f$ decays rapidly enough). Moreover, by the first part of the question then Hölder’s inequality \begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R^{2d}} \rho_f f M^{1/2} \, dv \,dx&\leq \| f\|_{L^2_{xv}(M^{-1/2})} \int_{\mathbb R^{2d}} \vert f  \vert M^{1/2} \, dv \,dx\leq  \| f\|_{L^2_{xv}(M^{-1/2})}^2=\phi(t),
\end{align*} so we obtain that $$\phi’(t)\leq 2\phi(t)-2\phi(t)=0 .$$ Thus, $\phi$ is decreasing, so $\phi(t) \leqslant \phi(0)$, that is, $$\| f\|_{L^2_{xv}(M^{-1/2})} \leq \| f_0\|_{L^2_{xv}(M^{-1/2})}. $$

Comment: thanks for your answer,and the variable in $\nabla$ is just x

Comment: @RIM Do you have more questions? If this answers everything then you can mark it as having answered your question

Comment: answered question §